# create record interface translation issue

Tags: lightning, community, event

I'm using the system event ' create record' to display a popup for new object creation in lightning community , in my community I'm using two languages english and arabic,
the issue is that objects names are not translated like in the image below, the objects: project, account and members are not translated,
I already translated these objects in rename abject & label but no use
[image]

I'm using this code to open create record interface:

```
  var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
            var RecordTypeID  = '';
            RecordTypeID= response.getReturnValue();

            createRecordEvent.setParams({
               "entityApiName": 'Project_Info__c',
               "recordTypeId": RecordTypeID
            });
            createRecordEvent.fire();
```